# Decorator converting given kwargs to attrs of function

Tags: python

I'm using most of the time construction like this:

```
def function(some,params):
    pass
function.arg1 = val1
function.arg2 = val2
```

But it's not perfectly DRY and it keeps annoying if I have dozens of args added to function or method like this and I need for some reason change function name, because I need to change all `function` into `function2` for example. Maybe there is an built in python decorator which I can use like this:

```
@some_decorator(arg1=val1, arg2=val2, arg3=val3)
def function(some, params):
    pass
```

It will save me lot of time when changin function name (or copying function with other name). Anyone knows if there is something built in python? I know that creating such decorator is no big deal, but then I must include it in all my projects, so it will be a lot easier to have it built in.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have so very many function attributes?

Comment: For example, adding custom columns in django admin (i know that's methods, not functions, but close enough in this situation) where setting column label and other attributes on column is made that way. In this example I don't need so much attributes, but sometimes I must copy one column dozen of times and change in copies only name and little bit something in code. Another example is I have some functions that I pass into interface class and that interface class knows what to do with function based on this attrs (interface is for querying game servers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job

```
from functools import wraps

def some_decorator(arg1, arg2):
    def wrapper(func):

       @wraps(func)
       def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
           func(*args, **kwargs)

       inner_wrapper.arg1 = arg1
       inner_wrapper.arg2 = arg2
       return inner_wrapper

    return wrapper
```

Of course you can chage `arg1` and `arg2` in decorator to `**kwargs` if this is more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for response, but actually does not solve my problem. I have similar code already, but I'm looking for built in decorator that will do the job (so I won't need to include this code in every project). But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word built-in in your question. I never heard about such decorator and I don't think it is available in standard library because it is not a common pattern.